# pgRouting problem: creating topology where segments touch

Tags: pgrouting, topology

I am working my way through the example in the pgRouting manual (2.2). After running pgr_createTopology() and pgr_analyzeGraph():

pgr_test=# SELECT pgr_createTopology('edge_table',0.001);
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('edge_table', 0.001, 'the_geom', 'id', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean := f)
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTICE:  Creating Topology, Please wait...
NOTICE:  -------------> TOPOLOGY CREATED FOR  18 edges
NOTICE:  Rows with NULL geometry or NULL id: 0
NOTICE:  Vertices table for table public.edge_table is: 
public.edge_table_vertices_pgr
NOTICE:  ----------------------------------------------
 pgr_createtopology
--------------------
 OK
(1 row)

pgr_test=# select pgr_analyzeGraph('edge_table', 0.001);
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_analyzeGraph('edge_table',0.001,'the_geom','id','source','target','true')
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait ...
NOTICE:  Analyzing for dead ends. Please wait...
NOTICE:  Analyzing for gaps. Please wait...
NOTICE:  Analyzing for isolated edges. Please wait...
NOTICE:  Analyzing for ring geometries. Please wait...
NOTICE:  Analyzing for intersections. Please wait...
NOTICE:              ANALYSIS RESULTS FOR SELECTED EDGES:
NOTICE:                    Isolated segments: 2
NOTICE:                            Dead ends: 7
NOTICE:  Potential gaps found near dead ends: 1
NOTICE:               Intersections detected: 1
NOTICE:                      Ring geometries: 0
 pgr_analyzegraph
------------------
 OK
(1 row)

So there are 2 isolated segments, which turn out to have id = 17, 18:

pgr_test=# SELECT a.* FROM edge_table a, edge_table_vertices_pgr b, edge_table_vertices_pgr c WHERE a.source=b.id AND b.cnt=1 AND a.target=c.id AND c.cnt=1;

 id | dir | source | target | cost | reverse_cost | x1  | y1  |       x2       | y2  |                                      the_geom
----+-----+--------+--------+------+--------------+-----+-----+----------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 17 | B   |     14 |     15 |    1 |            1 | 0.5 | 3.5 | 1.999999999999 | 3.5 | 010200000002000000000000000000E03F0000000000000C4068EEFFFFFFFFFF3F0000000000000C40

 18 | B   |     16 |     17 |    1 |            1 | 3.5 | 2.3 |            3.5 |   4 | 0102000000020000000000000000000C4066666666666602400000000000000C400000000000001040

The id=18 case is due to crossing and can be fixed later by pgr_nodeNetwork(), but the id=17 case is due to touching and I thought it should be handled by createTopology(), and it persisted even after pgr_nodeNetwork(). I tried bigger tolerance values to no avail. The manual says tolerance is in projection unit, but I don't know whether this is relevant for the sample data in the manual?

I am using pgRouting-2.2.0 on Windows with Postgresql-9.5, PostGIS-2.2.

Comment: I updated pgrouting to 2.2.2 but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The pgr_nodeNetwork code was modified on version 2.1
I confirm there is a bug on that modification.

```
SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('edge_table', 0.001);
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_nodeNetwork('edge_table', 0.001, 'id', 'the_geom', 'noded', '<NULL>',  f)
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTICE:  Processing, please wait .....
NOTICE:    Splitted Edges: 2
NOTICE:   Untouched Edges: 16
NOTICE:       Total original Edges: 18
NOTICE:   Edges generated: 4
NOTICE:   Untouched Edges: 16
NOTICE:         Total New segments: 20
NOTICE:   New Table: public.edge_table_noded
NOTICE:  ----------------------------------
 pgr_nodenetwork 
-----------------
 OK
(1 row)
```

where it reads

```
NOTICE:    Splitted Edges: 2
```

should be

```
NOTICE:    Splitted Edges: 3
```

I opened the following issue:
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/612

Will be fixed for next release on September, 
Thank you for noticing.

pgRouting team